# How to use flex functions outside the lex.l file?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have two functions that look like this:

```
void init_analysis(){
    yyin = stdin;
    flag_console = TRUE;
    line = 1;
    yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer( yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE ));
}

void terminate_analysis(){
    yypop_buffer_state();
}
```

They are inside a file called lex.l which when it is compiled with the command 'flex lex.l' generates a file called lex.yy.c. What I want to do is to declare and implement these two functions outside this file lex.l in a file called, for example utilities.c with its correspondent utilities.h. The problem is that I cannot move these two functions to another file because they have functions like yypop_buffer_state and datatypes like YY_BUFFER_STATE which are not defined in the new file I want to move the functions (these elements are only defined in the lex.yy.c file). How can I move these functions?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation for flex, you can use the following parameter when running flex

```
--header-file=my_flex_header_file.h
```

which generates a header file that you can include in your other files.